# How Do You Set a Textblock to Autosize to the Width of a TreeView?

Tags: wpf, textblock, autosize

I have a `TextBlock` that I need to autosize to the width of a `TreeView`.  The `TreeView` and the `TextBlock` are both contained in a `StackPanel`.  The `StackPanel` is inside an `Expander`.  The width of the `TreeView` should drive the width of the other objects and I need the height of the `TextBlock` to change to display the full text.  All my efforts have resulted in the `TextBlock` driving the width.  Thanks!

```
       <Expander IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,8,53" x:Name="ExpanderBookMarks" Width="Auto" Foreground="#FF625B5B" ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="True" Header="Bookmarks" Visibility="Hidden">

        <StackPanel Name ="StackPanelBookmark" Orientation="Vertical" Width="{wpf:Binding Path=Width, ElementName=trvBookmarks, Mode=Default}">

            <TreeView x:Name="trvBookmarks" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource BookmarkTemplateSelector}" 
              Margin="0,0,0,0" 
              TreeViewItem.Selected="HandleTreeViewItemClick" AllowDrop="True"/>

            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockBookmarkDiscription" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Background="Transparent" Width="150">
                This is the discription area and needs to be very long because the end user can put 400 charectors in.                    
            </TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--End of Dougs Treeview-->

    </Expander>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=trvBookmarks,Path=ActualWidth}" ... />
```